# Adding ImageIcon to JPanel not working

Tags: java, jpanel, panel, imageicon

I am trying to add an ImageIcon to my JPanel.

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("image.png", null);
JLabel label = new JLabel(image, JLabel.CENTER);
panel.add(label);
```

Ok. The image is is located in the same folder as the class...

```
com.package
          |- mainclass.java
          |- image.png
          V
```

For whatever reason, the imageicon will not display in the JPanel. 
I try/catch-ed it, but no use. No errors at all!

I am on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ImageIcon(String)` assumes that the specified String value is a file on the file system

Based on you description I would guess that the image is embedded within the application, meaning that it is not longer accessible as a File, but instead needs to accessed as a `URL` or `InputStream`

Because the image and class are in the same package you can use something like

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image.png"));
```

Assuming you're loading it from `MainClass`

Comment: Ok, now there is no nullpointerexception, but it didn't display the image! :( (Sorry!!!)

Comment: Either there was an error loading the image or there is something wrong with the way you are adding the JLabel

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the `full path`, seeing it from the `root` of your application.

In your case, you must use `new ImageIcon("com/package/image.png", null)`.

Comment: But the full path will change, because the computer will be different (This is a program to be on the internet later...) Do you mean I only have to also specify the package?

Comment: Yes, you must specify the package, not the actual location of your JAR. For example, if your image is located on the package "resources" inside your JAR, then use "resources/image.png".

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

I looked at some old code with a similar situation turns out I added the image to a JLabel first and then to the JPanel.

Try adding the Image to a JLabel and then add that JLabel to the JPanel as follows.

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("image.png"));
JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(image);
panel.add(picLabel);
```

Comment: Is the image located in the same package?